# Simple single server CoreOS setup at some hosting provider?

Tags: coreos

[CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) seems like a good distro for hosting web services: automatic updates, low memory usage, built in Docker support. However, all installation instructions seem to assume that I'm going to configure a whole fleet of servers. — Is there no simple way to skip all complicated setup and just get CoreOS running at some hosting provider on a single server, as were it a "normal" distro like Ubuntu?

For example, do I really have to configure `etcd` service discovery when I'll run my app server and PostgreSQL on a single server?

If there is no simple way today, do you think there will be in the more distant future? Or will CoreOS always be only for massive multi server deployments?

(Background: I hope I'll one day be writing instructions for other people about how to install a certain web app I'm developing, and it'd be nice if I could instruct them to use CoreOS, knowing they'd get up and running quickly and easily.)

Comment: In which direction could this question possibly be edited, so it becomes on-topic and professional? — Two things I can think about are 1) to remove the "Background" section. And 2) to actually try to install CoreOS without e.g. configuring `etcd` and including in the question the results of doing that. Am I on the right track? (I probably wouldn't have time to do that within the next few days though.)

Comment: (There is no other StackExchange site where this question would be on-topic? What about SuperUser?)

Answer (score 3):

DigitalOcean just added support for CoreOS (yesterday actually), and they've written a step by step guide on how to get a minimal setup running:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-coreos-cluster-on-digitalocean

That's probably one of the easier routes to getting CoreOS running somewhere.

Comment: That step-by-step guide is the reason for my question :-) I also found it, and thought "I cannot ask the users of my software to read and understand this guide. They won't have time for that. Does it really have to be this complicated?"

Answer (score 1):

For a really simple setup, just boot an image on a supported cloud provider and supply an SSH key through that providers UI or via cloud config.

You can skip all of the etcd and fleet stuff and be ready to use docker out of the box.

SSH user is core by default.

Comment: Have you tested this, or are you thinking that it ought to work? If you have a look at [Digital Oceans's CoreOS guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-coreos-cluster-on-digitalocean), can I really skip e.g. the steps *Generate a New Discovery URL* and *Write a Cloud-Config File*?